# How can I make css fit my content without spaces

Tags: css, html, margin, padding, spacing

I have a image uploading system but I want when the User uploads his/her picture
that it fits perfect under or beside each other! like this

[image: http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/858857_512093658832576_175558807_o.jpg]

Comment: What have you [tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: i tried to set my marging to 0 but it doenst work

Comment: Search for "masonry" here. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create divs for every column, and float left those columns.
I recommend you to use some jquery plugin. [Like this](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (jQuery masonry)

1. [Another Collage](http://plugins.jquery.com/collage/)
2. [Kelt Dokins collage](https://github.com/kdocki/jquery-collage)
3. [Kelt Dokins - Collage Demo](http://www.keltdockins.com/2/post/2012/08/jquery-collage-plugin.html)